# How to use $filter('filter') when filtering more than one column using OR as a condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of **customers** in AngularJs Application.

```
var customers = [
    {
        "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }
];
```

My question is how to filter using multiple columns. I tried below code and it doesn't work.

```
$scope.customers = (
    $filter('filter')(customers, {
        Name: $scope.criteria.searchtext,
        City: $scope.criteria.searchtext
    })
);
```

**EDIT**

How to convert above syntax to **'OR'** Please check [Sample](http://codepen.io/AliAdravi/pen/RPOQQQ) for the reference.

Comment: depends on what your search criteria is. *"doesn't work"* isn't very informative

Comment: Are you sure It is not working? I have tested and it works. Be aware that that syntax filters with an "and", this means that the condition would be something like "Take the objects with a name that contains this text AND a city that contains the same text". Is an "OR" what you need?

Comment: @AlvaroVazquez Yeah "OR" is what I need sorry if I confused you guys

Comment: and is it absolute match or partial match?

Comment: partial match will do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using a custom angular filter I typically just use `Array.prototype.filter()` although you can also use a function argument with `$filter`

Following assumes partial match

```
$scope.customers =  customers.filter(item){
     var term = $scope.criteria.searchtext.toLowerCase();
     //partial match 
     return item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >-1 
            || item.City.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >-1;

});
```

this can quickly be turned into an angular custom filter also to use in the view

Answer (score 0):

Add filter in customers

```
<tr class="animate" ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter: criteria.searchtext">
<td ng-bind="customer.Name"></td>
<td ng-bind="customer.City"></td>
<td ng-bind="customer.Country"></td>
</tr>
```

And then move customers to the `$scope` as follow

```
$scope.customers = [{}]; // Will be array of customers
```

Check this [Solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRJLLR?editors=1111)

Let us know if this works for you or not.

Comment: See how I added a `filter: criteria.searchtext` which is what you will be searching through and it will filter your records. Give it a try and let us know. I have tested it myself and worked.

Answer (score -1):

I created a new **Custom filter** to filter multiple columns using `OR` condition check this,

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope,myFilterFilter) {
  $scope.criteria = {};
  $scope.criteria.searchtext = 'Berlin';
  var customers =[{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
{"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},{"Name":"Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany asfdasdas"}]
$scope.customers=myFilterFilter(customers,$scope.criteria.searchtext,$scope.criteria.searchtext);
 
}


angular.module('myApp').filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(customers,name,city) {
      var yes = [];
      angular.forEach(customers, function(value, key) {
        if ((value['Name'] === name) || (value['City'] === city)) {
           yes.push(value);              
        }
        
    });
    console.log(yes)
    return yes
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  Hello, {{customers}}!
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10336/)

Comment: Please check the answer or put a reason before downvoting.